# How should I indent do nothing initialization list constructors?

Tags: c++, indentation

Example: `Thread::Thread`:

```
class Thread
{
    Process * parent_;
    unsigned __int32 id_;
    void * entryPoint_;
public:
    Thread(Process * parent, unsigned __int32 id, void * entryPoint) : 
        parent_(parent),
        id_(id),
        entryPoint_(entryPoint)
    {
    }
    unsigned __int32 GetId() const
    {
        return id_;
    }
    void * GetEntryPointAddress() const
    {
        return entryPoint_;
    }
};
```

I can't seem to come up with a way of indenting things so that it doesn't look strange... and yet this is a common pattern. What are common ways of indenting this?

Comment: As I've answered questions like this before: As long as your'e consistent, it really doesn't matter. :) (That said, I'm curious why you think it looks strange. It looks perfectly fine to me. :)

Comment: put it all in one line and don't think about it! :D

Comment: @greyfade: Part of being consistent is doing what others do. I've never seen anyone express an opinion on this, so I asked. Don't know exactly why -- just makes me cringe for some reason. @ybungalobill: That makes merging things in source control difficult.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I always put empty blocks on a single line – i.e. `{ }` (notice the space!).

Furthermore, I usually put the colon and commas *in front of* the initialization list members instead of after – this makes adding members later on easier.

```
Thread(Process * parent, unsigned __int32 id, void * entryPoint)
    : parent_(parent)
    , id_(id)
    , entryPoint_(entryPoint)
{ }
```

(Edit: I no longer follow this style myself: I omit the space between braces nowadays.)

Comment: BTW (even though i don't use this style) this style may be good because it's the only one MS Visual Studio will not mess up with its automatic formatting.

Comment: Sometimes when it looks like there should be code I add a comment /* Deliberately Empty */ (but only if it needs to be explained).

Comment: @Martin: Would you add one here?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: It depends a lot on context (and we don;t have much here). But I may add a comment. /* This is not the thread start point. This initializes the thread object. The `Thread of execution` will later be started by calling the method XXXX() */

Comment: nice formatting, I like the fact that adding / commenting members is made easy. @Martin: I prefer to use `//` comments, `/**/` just don't nest, so they are a pain.

Comment: Why is the space important?

Comment: @pydave It isn’t *important* but the question was about formatting preferences, and I prefer to space empty braces with a space to make them stand out more – *especially* when they are a placeholder for a whole block. Just `{}` is slightly too innocuous for my taste, and leaving a line break between them takes up too much vertical space.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it:

```
Thread(Process * parent, unsigned __int32 id, void * entryPoint) 
    :parent_(parent),
     id_(id),
     entryPoint_(entryPoint)
{}
```

But your way does not look strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it

```
public:
    Thread(Process * parent, unsigned __int32 id, void * entryPoint) : 
    parent_(parent),
    id_(id),
    entryPoint_(entryPoint) 
    { }
```

Google style (atleast protobuf), would be:

```
public:
 Thread(Process * parent, 
        unsigned __int32 id, 
        void * entryPoint) 
  : parent_(parent),
    id_(id),
    entryPoint_(entryPoint) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it, and why I don't see anything wrong with your sample:

```
Thread(Process * parent, unsigned __int32 id, void * entryPoint) : 
        parent_(parent),
        id_(id),
        entryPoint_(entryPoint) { }
```

As far as I'm concerned, do it your way: As long as you are self-consistent and consistent with the project you're working on, it doesn't *matter* what your indentation style is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend putting a comment into the empty constructor body, just so anyone reading the code knows that you intended it to be empty.  That way they can be certain that it's not a case of you having forgotten to insert code there.

```
Thread(Process * parent, unsigned __int32 id, void * entryPoint) : 
    parent_(parent),
    id_(id),
    entryPoint_(entryPoint)
{
    // empty
}
```

Comment: you know what, I actually don't like this because it will frighten somebody to put code here later. But if its necessary the maintainer should not be coereced/biaised into thinking not to do that by a scary comment.

Comment: "empty" is a scary comment, really?  I guess one could be more explicit e.g. "// I intentionally didn't put any code here, but you go ahead if you think it's the right thing to do" but I think that might be a bit overkill.  Either comment will be less scary to a maintainer than forcing him to try to guess what the original author's intent was, due to the absence of any clues about why the method body is empty.